# Which UK visa category for MRCP UK PACES clinical exams

Tags: visas, uk

I am a Doctor who has completed the MRCP UK part 1 and 2 exams and now I have secured admissions to sit for the part 2 clinicals in the UK. I have the admission documents and the Visa letter from the royal college of Physicians. 
My question is which Visa category should I select in order to sit for this exam. Because there is no specific visa in order to enter the UK for an exam. 
My circumstances in terms of employment and finances are all in order. In addition, as I want to make the most of a trip to the UK I want my 2 kids and husband also to accompany me so that we can do some sightseeing. 
Hence, please give me your thoughts on which visa category I should apply for all of us. 
We have traveled to the UK in 2017 for tourism on a 7 day trip. Also have a schengen visa in 2017 and we traveled to 9 European countries. In addition I have traveled to the UK another time before, 19 years ago while I was studying medicine in Moscow. I am a South Asian. We also have a good travel history.

Comment: Do the visa letter have some clues? I would use short term study for you (adding that you will do some tourism, to have some extra days), and tourism for your family (but after you got your visa).

Comment: See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y It’s usually a Standard Visitor visa for an exam https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules If there’s a period of study attached for more than 30 days but less than 6 months it would be a Short-term Study visa https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa

Comment: may i learn which visa application have you applied for mrcp exam?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.

Comment: Yusufi, I thought I answered this question for you but since no answers are showing up, I'll answer it again. Hope I'm not too late. I applied for a standard 6 months tourist visa with all my examination details and obtained the visa on time. I have since entered the UK twice on that visa, once for the exams and once for tourism. Good luck.